# Возврат на главный экран (routing)

Tags: flutter, dart

Есть приложение с таким вот роутингом:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MATH',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
        '/': (context) => MyCustomForm(),
        // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
        '/1': (context) => FirstRoute(),
        '/2': (context) => SecondRoute(),
        '/3': (context) => ThirdRoute(),
        '/final': (context) => FinalScreen(),
      },

    );
  }
}
```

переключение происходит таким образом

```
onPressed: ()
{
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/" + page_id));
}
```

Как сделать чтобы с любой страницы при свайпе влево (назад) или с AppBar (стрелка назад) возврат был всегда на главную страницу( "/" )? Сейчас возврат идет на предыдущую так как они друг за другом открываются(/, 1, 2, 3, final)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MATH',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyCustomForm(),
        '/1': (context) => FirstRoute(),
        '/2': (context) => SecondRoute(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("MyCustomForm"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/" + 1.toString()),
            child: Text('Go next!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("FirstRoute"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/" + 2.toString()),
            child: Text('Go next 2!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("SecondRoute"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
            child: Text('Go back!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: а в случае с свайпом влево (назад)? Здесь судя по всему только к кнопке в верхнем меню привязан возврат на главную страницу.

Comment: @АлексейБондарь а у вас свайпы из cupertino widget? Или имеете ввиду системные кнопки (свайпы)? `Go back!` тоже на главную страницу ведёт.

Comment: @АлексейБондарь обновил ответ. На устройстве не проверял, но по идее должно работать.

Comment: теперь свайп влево почему-то никуда не ведет. Просто не работает.

Comment: `@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MATH'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(`

Comment: @АлексейБондарь а так: `onWillPop: (){
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
return Future.value(false);
}`

Comment: работает! В очередной раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейБондарь всегда пожалуйста! Как я понял `leading:` в `AppBar` не обязательно прописывать если есть `onWillPop`.